# input text styling of input field html css

Tags: html, forms, css

I've got an input field with one line on the bottom, much like a line of a textbook. I want to  be able to display the placeholder text as well as the text the user inputs just a little above the line.

I've made a fiddle over here: http://jsfiddle.net/H7AVP/

This is what my HTML looks like:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="subscribe for early access" class="form-control email">
```

And my CSS (not cross-browser optimized for the question):

```
.email::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-bottom:45px;
  margin-top:-10px;
}

input {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  outline: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px;
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom-style: double;
  border-bottom-color: #34495e;
  height: 46px;
  width: 300px;
}

input:focus{
  outline:0;
}
textarea:focus{
  outline:0;
}
```

Comment: so you want the text to appear closer to the line? like this: http://jsfiddle.net/H7AVP/1/ ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516303/how-to-keep-input-placeholder-visible-when-user-is-typing see this for information.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way that comes to my mind would be setting `line-height` on `input` to about `40px`. As it has a fixed height, this will work just fine to move the text to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding you want your placeholder and input to be in center.

add the following

```
.email{
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

and in form > div > input css file add {height :30px;}

here is the http://jsfiddle.net/H7AVP/

Answer (score 0):

Here are two variations:

1:  http://jsfiddle.net/H7AVP/5/

By default, removing any specific `height` or `padding` will keep the text "snug" with it's surrounding border. From there, just add padding to the left/right + padding to the top. I believe this should give you the effect you want.

After that, just move the styles you are using for `-webkit-input-placeholder` in the generic input itself. Then, if you just want to differentiate on color, then add it specifically to `-webkit-input-placeholder`.

Also, updated to use shorthand CSS methods wherever possible.

2:  http://jsfiddle.net/H7AVP/6/

Now, if you want your text to get friendlier with the bottom border, then just simply apply a set `height` to the input element. The top `padding` will make sure your text is "snug" to the bottom.