# place holder like after text in text box

Tags: html, css

we want to show some notification in textbox after text. 
Like, If filter is activated, then we want to show 'Filter Activated', Just after the text. 
Text is entered by the user, So if they change the text of text box, then it automatically adjust according to length of the text.

For example:-

[Sample image creation](http://collabshot.com/show/oOh9TJ)

I tried this

**[`JsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/4t05kh2p/)**

But it is always on the right side or always on left side.

```css
#clear {
right: 39px;
background: #f1f1f1;
color: rgb(187, 187, 187);
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;
width: 104px;
height: 36px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
/* right: 2px; */
top: 2px;
 }
.search-form {
width: 100%;
padding-right: 52px;
font-size: 19px;
font-family: 'Merriweather', sans-serif;
font-style: italic;
height:30px;
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="auto" class="search-form" >
<div id="clear">Filtering active</div>
```

NOT DUPLICATE:-

```
 Place holder is different from this. Place holder is talking about the text box, What text box can contain. But this is talking about the filtering.
```

Comment: i dont think so its possible with that little code ... check chosen plugin it looks something like that

Comment: Little code? 
So how can we achieve this?

Comment: with pure css this is impossible. You can set the filter or whatever inside the input text, but you cannot adjust it right next to the text

Comment: if there is only one value than it doesnt make any sense to have it just after value

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep input placeholder visible when user is typing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516303/how-to-keep-input-placeholder-visible-when-user-is-typing)

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible in HTML/CSS without a little javascript.

I've made a quick working exemple with one possibility and jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/4t05kh2p/1/

The idea is to copy entered text in an invisible span that will push your label to the right:

HTML:

```
<div id="group">
  <input type="text" id="auto" class="search-form" >
  <div id="clear"><span class="spacer"></span><span class="text">Filtrering aktiv</span></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#auto').on('keyup', function(){
  $('#clear .spacer').text($(this).val());
});
```

CSS:

```
#clear {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  top: 16px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 0;
}
#clear .spacer {
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 19px;
}
#clear .text {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 3px;
}
.search-form {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 19px;
  height:30px;
}
```

Comment: though it works but its really not working like we want just type and than click on text .. you can edit on clicking text because space overlape it though +1 for efforts

Comment: It was working on firefox, but with a few ajustments, it can work in other browsers too (http://jsfiddle.net/4t05kh2p/2/)

Comment: check this out http://jsfiddle.net/31gx15n3/  i have just edited little bit css now its working fine... your example is really nice

Comment: This is somewhat i want. Need some modification. Let me check after that i will accept this answer. BTW voted up to understand my requirements.

Comment: Its working fine, But the problem is now i am unable to click on text box due to invisible span.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use some black magic: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsv3s60o/)

I wrote it from scratch, so add some of your styling.

```js
$('.inputText').on('keyup', function () {
  var value = $(this).text();  
  $('#hidden').val(value).change();
});

$('#hidden').on('change', function () {
  var text = $(this).val();
  $('.test').html(text);
});
$('.clear').on('click', function () {
  alert('Hello!');
});
```

```css
.input {
    position: relative;  
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
.inputText {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 150px;
    outline: none;
}
.clear {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden" >     
    <span class='input'>
        <span contenteditable='true' class='inputText'> </span>
        <span class='clear'>Filtrering aktiv</span>
    </span>    
</div>
<div>
    <small class='test'></small>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry But its not what i want. Here 'Filtring aktiv' is constant, Its not moving. I want to add 'Filtring aktiv' just after the text. text is short or long.

Comment: @RenuThakur  'Filtring aktiv' isn't constant, it is moving, try to type some more text. And also you can change .inputText min-width property and make initial width of input as small as you wish.

Comment: Yes, Right. Can you please check this once https://www.booli.se/ystad/117021/?direction=desc&sort=published&rooms=3