# Keep input placeholder text visible after user input

Tags: html, css

I want to make a placeholder stay visible after writing something in the input field.

Important:
I don't want to use any other elements to 'workaround' this problem, I want to use just the input field.  Please just CSS, no JS or jQuery.

Comment: Do you want placeholder text that just stays behind the text you write in? Won't that look a little odd?

Comment: [Already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19516489/1523400)

Comment: simply use value="Whatever placeholder name you want" in the input....something like <input type="text" name="name" value="placeholder">

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep input placeholder visible when user is typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516303/how-to-keep-input-placeholder-visible-when-user-is-typing)

Answer (score 4):

Use `data-placeholder` property on `class ="placeholder"` so :

```
<div class="placeholder" data-placeholder="New placeholder">
</div>
```

and in Css :

```
.placeholder {
    position: relative;
}

.placeholder::after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 2px;
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Here is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Panther_007/f1wht1hw/5/)